# for php, how to lowercase or uppercase a character in a string

Tags: php

I tried the following, it doesn't seem to work

```
if ($word[$index] >= 'a' && $word[$index] <= 'z') {
  $word[$index] = $word[$index] - 'a' + 'A';
} else if ($word[$index] >= 'A' && $word[$index] <= 'Z') {
  $word[$index] = $word[$index] - 'A' + 'a';
}
```

Anything wrong here? What's the best way to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Let me clarify this: you want some particular character to become lowercased, if it was uppercased, and vice versa?

Comment: @raina77ow I get the same impression from the question.

Comment: What is not working for you right now ?

Comment: I believe everybody mistook his intent and he did not come back to explain: he wants to change the case of ONE character inside a string. I'm looking for the best way to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the case of the entire string, try: `strtoupper( $string )` or `strtolower( $string )`. If you want to change just the case of the first letter of the string, try: `ucfirst( $string)` or `lcfirst( $string )`.

There is also `str_replace()`, which is case-sensitive. You could do something like `str_replace( 'a', 'A', $string );` to replace all lowercase letter 'a' with uppercase letter 'A'.

You may want to have a look at a list of the [php string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Comment: looks like he wants to change the case of every element.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your trying to invert the case ?

```
$word =  strtolower($word) ^ strtoupper($word) ^ $word;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inverse the case of all the letters in the string, here's one possible approach:

```
$test = 'StAcK oVeЯfLoW';
$letters = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $test );
foreach ($letters as &$le) {
    $ucLe = mb_strtoupper($le, 'UTF8');
    if ($ucLe === $le) {
        $le = mb_strtolower($le, 'UTF8');
    }
    else {
        $le = $ucLe;
    }
}
unset($le); 
$reversed_test = implode('', $letters);
echo $reversed_test; // sTaCk OvEяFlOw
```